# Creating a folder using Azure Storage Rest API without creating a default blob file

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to create following folder structure on Azure:

```
mycontainer
   -images
       --2007
           ---img001.jpg
           ---img002.jpg
```

Now, one way is to use PUT Blob request and upload img001.jpg specifying the whole path as

> PUT "mycontainer/images/2007/img001.jpg"

But, I want to first create the folders `images` and `2007` and then in a different request upload the blob `img001.jpg`.

Right now when I tried to doing this using `PUT BLOB` request:

> StringToSign:

```
PUT











x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob
x-ms-date:Tue, 07 Feb 2017 23:35:12 GMT
x-ms-version:2016-05-31
/account/mycontainer/images/
```

> HTTP URL

```
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection:http://account.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/images/
```

> It is creating a folder but its not empty. By, default its creating an
>   empty blob file without name.

Now, a lot of people say we can't create a empty folder. But, then how come, we can make it using the azure portal as the browser must be sending some type of rest request to create the folder.

I think it has to do something with `Content-Type` i.e. `x-ms-blob-content-type`, which should be specified in order to tell azure that its a folder not a blob.
But, I am confused.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to first create the folders images and 2007 and then in a different request upload the blob img001.jpg

I agree with Brendan Green, currently, Azure blob storage just enable us to create virtual directory structure by naming blobs with path information in their names.

> I think it has to do something with Content-Type i.e. x-ms-blob-content-type, which should be specified in order to tell azure that its a folder not a blob. But, I am confused.

You could check [the description of Request Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/put-blob) that could be set for `Put Blob` operation and you will find it does not support creating an empty folder by specifying some request headers.

Besides, as Gaurav Mantri said, if you really want to create an empty folder structure without content, you could try to use [Azure File storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files) and it also enables us to [use REST API to access Azure File storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/file-service-rest-api). And the `Create Directory` operation cloud be used to create a new directory under the specified share or parent directory.

> PUT https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/myshare/myparentdirectorypath/mydirectory?restype=directory

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible - the folder structure is virtual only.

See [Get started with Azure Blob storage using .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs).  You can only create a container, and everything else held in that container is a blob.

Excerpt:

> As shown above, you can name blobs with path information in their
>   names. This creates a virtual directory structure that you can
>   organize and traverse as you would a traditional file system. Note
>   that the directory structure is virtual only - the only resources
>   available in Blob storage are containers and blobs.

Comment: But, in amazon, I am able to do it. Why is it causing problem in Azure?

Comment: Last I checked with S3, it also has 2 level hierarchy: Bucket & Objects. On a side note, if you really need a true folder like structure you may also want to look into Azure File Service. There you can create a directory without any contents.

Comment: @GauravMantri You can give path with forward slash in amazon to create an empty folder like "images/"